# Is there a way to make this whole code shorter?

Tags: java

I am currently struggling with one thing about this assignment. I would just like a way to make the whole code shorter, even just a little bit (especially the `if` statement).

```
package Integers;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int positive = 0;

        System.out.println ("-Input ten non-zero integers to calculate their sum. " + "\n" + "-Input the integers at the console and press <Enter>" + "\n");

        System.out.println ("Input the 1st integer:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int num1 = input.nextInt ();

        System.out.println ("Input the 2nd integer:");
        int num2 = input.nextInt ();

        System.out.println ("Input the 3rd integer:");
        int num3 = input.nextInt ();

        System.out.println ("Input the 4th integer:");
        int num4 = input.nextInt ();

        System.out.println ("Input the 5th integer:");
        int num5 = input.nextInt ();

        {   if (num1 > 0)
                positive++;
        }
        {   if (num2 > 0)
                positive++;
        }
        {   if (num3 > 0)
                positive++;
        }
        {   if (num4 > 0)
                positive++;
        }
        {   if (num5 > 0)
                positive++;
        }

        System.out.println ("The number of positive integers are: " + positive);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the "Input the ** integer" string matter can it be more generic?

Comment: Learn about for loops. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: And learn about [arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: Voting to close this because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find yourself writing very similar code over and over again (or even copy-pasting stuff), there is always a way to generalise the code and put in into a for loop or an extra method. And that is the way to go.
In your case you could just simply use a for loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int positive = 0;
  System.out.println("Input the integers at the console and press <Enter>");

  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("Input the " + i + "st integer:");
    int x = input.nextInt();
    if (x > 0) positive++;
  }
  input.close();
  System.out.println ("The number of positive integers are: " + positive );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    String place = i + "th";
        if (i == 1)
            place = "1st";
        if (i == 2)
            place = "2nd";
        if (i == 3)
            place = "3rd";
        System.out.println("Input the " + place + " integer:");
    if (input.nextInt() > 0)
        positive++;
}

input.close();

System.out.println("The number of positive integers are: " + positive);
```

Comment: "Input the 2st integer"?

Comment: hrm, maybe `int n = (i % 10);` and `(n == 1) ? "st" : (n == 2) ? "nd" : (n == 3) ? "rd" : "th"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the variable for later use, you can Use array to make it easier.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] array = new int[5];
int positive = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    array[i]=input.nextInt();
    if (array[i] > 0)
       positive++;
}
System.out.println("Number of positive elements are"+ positive);
```